# Fitting merged polygon within adjacent line features using QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to fit the polygon into the adjacent lines, when moving my object to the different location and can it be done automatically?

[image]

Once I moved feature, I am unsure about it location within the borderlines lying next to. I would like to make them fitted to the polygon edge.

[image]

Comment: If you're asking how to snap your polygon feature to a nearby line, try using the Vertex Tool to move it instead of the Move Feature tool. Simply activate the vertex tool, click and drag to select all the vertices of the polygon, and move the polygon. When it gets near the line, it will snap to that line (according to your snapping settings; make sure snapping is turned on).

Comment: Yes, I would like to snap the polygon feature to the nearby line, although I want to move my feature at once alongside the lines. The vertex tool helps me to do it, but I am losing an initial shape and don't move it correctly.

Comment: You can move an entire feature with the vertex tool. Select all the vertices of the feature before moving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough, when I pull my feature alongside the one of the line, keeping it as close as I can. Then I don't need to worry about its path.

[image]

Comment: Ok, done. I didn't know that my own answer can be also accepted by myself. Thanks